# Why do I get the message of missing .bash and .sh files in the terminal starts?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

First, I apologize  if this is not the appropriate question, however, in the second thought it may qualify. Everytime I get the following message of missing files at the starts of the Mac terminal,

```
-bash: /Users/Chaklader/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/Chaklader/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
```

Though, everything works fine, I just curious why do I get the message and what should I do to eliminate it ?

Comment: look at ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc files. One of them might be trying to execute scripts at the paths mentioned in the errors above.

Comment: This is what happened and after I commented those 2 lines, the errors stopped.

Answer (score -1):

If you add these lines to your `~/.bash_profile` it should clear them up.

```
. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash
. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh
```

Discussion [Here](https://gist.github.com/trey/2722934) with other solutions as well :) Hope this helps!

Comment: This won't help with the actual issue of trying to source non-existing files.